# Need circuit diagram for hp-r650ff3 power supply

Tags: hardware, electrical-power, power-supply-unit

Can somebody please provide a **circuit diagram** for a **HIPRO HP-R650FF3** swappable power supply unit? One of those which is built in one of our main servers went down after a company wide power failure and does not restart.

We have an electronic engineering department in-house which probably could repair it but they need a circuit diagram because some of the ICs or transistors might be broken and should be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but HP don't disclose them. Even if I'm a certified HP technician I can't see them.

Please order a new's one under warranty or via the store. That would at the same time prevent any possible error in a homemade repair that could damage your server.